# How to surpress RVM status messages when opening new bash shell?

Tags: bash, rvm

Every time I open a new bash shell the following messages print to my terminal:

```
Using /Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
Running /Users/foo/.rvm/hooks/after_use
```

I am running RVM version 1.15.8 across Linux and OS X environments and both boxes are experiencing this issue. How do I surpress these messages?

EDIT: The second message appeared to be caused by a script in the after_use directory. Rather than deleting the directory and the scripts that it contains entirely I would like to know what, precisely, is causing this so I can comment out only that line.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a `after_use` hook

[RVM website](https://rvm.io/workflow/hooks/) tells us:

> Each hook is a file in ~/.rvm/hooks/[hook name] in which you can place
>   any sequence of bash scripting commands. Each hook file when run will
>   have available to it the entire RVM environment.

I am guessing deleting `/USers/foo/.rvm/hooks/after_use` will fix this

Comment: Renaming the `hooks` directory prevents `Running…after_use` from printing, however, `Using…-p194` continues to print.

Comment: check the file called after_use in the hooks folder

Comment: @mmwtsn: `Using…-p194` comes from the `rvm use …` command in the dir's .rvmrc. If you take out `use` it will be silent.

Answer (score 0):

For next visitor of this question [learned from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222770/how-to-do-a-completely-silent-install-of-rvm):

you can dump the output to /dev/null using file descriptors

STDOUT (file descriptor 1) is redirected first, followed by STDERR (file descriptor 2)

`rvm --default use 2.4.0 > /dev/null 2>&1`

which will give no output at all to the screen/STDOUT whatsoever