# how to do a completely silent install of rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, silent

How to install rvm silently, suppressing stdout and stderr.

I tried

```
\curl -s -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s --quiet-curl


bash: --: invalid option
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can dump the output to `/dev/null` using file descriptors

STDOUT (file descriptor 1) is redirected first, followed by STDERR (file descriptor 2)

```
\curl -s -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s > /dev/null 2>&1
```